# Embed not sending nextcord

Tags: embed, nextcord

I wanted to make an addrole command with an embed and it does not want to send.

I tried doing this code.

```
@client.command()
async def r(ctx, role:nextcord.Role , member:nextcord.Member):
    embeds = nextcord.Embed(title = "Role given!", description = f'You have given the role {role.mention} to {member.mention}!')
    await ctx.send(embeds = embeds)
```

But it did not work

Answer (score 1):

you are using embed**s** meaning you are trying to send multiple embeds
if you are sending 1 embed you need to use

```
await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

try read this
https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#nextcord.ext.commands.Context.send